# Click through an android view that's called last to a dialog below

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, dialog

I've searched for hours, and I've not found the solution I need (at least one I can understand and implement).

I've gotten this far:

1. When a user clicks on a button in a game view to start a new game, I call an xml ad layout, that displays for X seconds. This same button calls a dialog that asks "Are you sure you want to start a new game" with yes or no buttons.
2. The ad displays beautifully using a translucent relative layout (so all I see is the add, and nothing else).

Here comes the issue. I'd like the ad to continue to show, while the user can click on the Dialog, and continue their game (with the ad view still showing)

I get the desired effect with using the

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

when calling my

```
setContentView(R.layout.ads);
```

But of course then the ads cannot be clicked on?! I need this effect while still allowing users to click on the ad at anytime.

I can usually figure this stuff out but I'm truly stumped! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain that when the dialog pops up over the ad, the ad will no longer be clickable.  On way around this would be to have the ad and the contents of the dialog in the same view.  The dialog components could be hidden for X seconds then shown.  Then the user could select either the ad or one of the buttons.  Certainly not a perfect solution however it is relatively simple and unlikely to break down the road.

There may be a way to do this with Fragments however I haven't done enough with them to be sure.